# Is MVC3 suitable for online games?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am planning to develop online economic games, but didn't find on internet that anyone do such project in MVC3. Is it wise to choose MVC3 as a framework for online economic game developing?

Answer (score 2):

It is. I personally developed a **browser based** economic game with a persistent world in 2009. Asp.net mvc 1 was good enough, mvc 3 is even better. I've used the mvc frameowrk for the UI layer. Of course the rest of the game, the real engine was in separate dlls with no connection to asp.net mvc.

It very much depends on what kind of game you want to make, but be aware that asp.net mvc is aimed at a web interface (html, flash). Anything else is just .net code which can work as a windows service. For my game, I could integratethe game engine in the asp.net mvc app without windows services because everything interacting with the game was browser based.

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 is a general web framework, that is suitable for many different kinds of web sites. It gives detailed control of the html generated and is easy to integrate with client side scripting. It is probably a good choice for an online game.

Later on you need to decide how much processing you want to do server side and what you want to do client side in javascript. That is probably the most important architectural decision you are up to.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it looks most online games is made on different frameworks. And didn't find that somebody was doing it on MVC3. So my questions would be why? Price? Speed?

Answer (score 1):

Despite of the fact that MVC3 in general is a web framework, it was honed mostly for business. And suit that needs perfectly. In the case of game development it has a some "bottleneck". First of all performance. Common performance is well, but you should take into account time GC decided to finalize things.

Secondly, almost all well spreaded server technology like ASP.NET, PHP, JSP use HTML that is best suit for static content like html page. Much better for game development is direct using of network socket connections.

Finally we can see that technology try to adapt for different needs and HTML5 become support of web socket connection. Moreover most of modern browsers whithin it last versions now support this technology. And even Microsoft promise include web socket support in MVC4. So, may be would be better to wait for the next version of MVC and use such a promising feature as web socket for your needs.

Comment: HTML is not a protocol, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be best looking at coding the game in Flash or Silverlight if it's to run in a browser.  Microsoft recently redid "Cut the Rope" to promote IE and they wrote the whole thing in HTML5 and CSS3.  This would be quite an undertaking though.

If it's to be run as a standalone application, i.e. something like World of Warcraft, then that is ran by a collection of central servers and a purpose made client.  The server holds what's going on in the game world and the client talks to the server and renders what's happening on your screen.  Most of these types of games are written in C++, but if you were doing something of a similar fashion but not to the same scale, you could probably get away with C# and the XNA or Direct X SDKs.

MVC is a framework for organising and delivering web page content.  Your game would most likely be embedded in a web page, so you could choose anything like Web Forms or MVC and it probably wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Both Silverlight and Flash are loosing ground, in favour of HTML5. Starting with something new I would prefer HTML5 over flash. Silverlight might be an option if the code is shared with a WPF desktop application, but not otherwise.